# Identify Podcasts in Smart Playlist?

Tags: itunes, smart-playlist

I'd like to exclude all podcast-type items from a Smart Playlist my iTunes library.  How can I identify podcasts so that I can exclude them from results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use **Media Kind is not Podcast** to deselect podcasts:

[image]

*Some* podcasts also have their **Genre** set to **Podcast**.

Answer (score 1):

I would pick **Media Kind *is not* Podcast** to solve the problem.

[image]